# Android: why button looks different in different API levels?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a **button** in my layout and I use a background for it. but this **button** looks different in different API levels.

In API 7 (Android 2.1)

[image]

In API 15 (Android 4.0.3)

[image]

and here is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="110px"
    android:layout_height="134px"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/imageview_bg" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="price" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_small_green_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should not use pixel values for your ImageView, but this is not your question. I don't know why it looks different, but I am guessing that the default padding/margin changes depending on the API (please correct me if I am wrong). Try setting the padding and margin of your button in the xml.

Comment: I agree with you. some parameters are different between API levels, but I don not know which one is. I changed the padding and layout_margin of the button but it does not affect the size of button in API level 15!

Answer (score 0):

Drawable folders are not managed properly. Provide proper background image for hdpi,mdpi,ldpi or whatever resolutions you want to support.

Comment: And yes as Perroloco suggest never use px. Always use dp or dip